# Use Feedburner instead of default feed on WordPress.com?

Tags: rss, feed, wordpress.com-hosting

How can I disable the default feed on WordPress.com and use Feedburner feed instead?

I know how I can in a self-hosted WordPress site, but I do not know how to in a free WordPress.com site.

[image: Feed icon in browser address bar]

[image: Feed icons on blog front-end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You can not disable the default WordPress.com feed but you have an option:

If you have the css upgrade, add `#feedarea {display:none;}` to remove the default links.   Use the feedburner widget code and add it to a text widget. Assign a class to it and using css absolute positioning move it to where the default links were.

**My Original Answer below only applies to self hosted WordPress**

Claim your feed URLs at [Feedburner](http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/myfeeds)

Then add this to your .htaccess under #END WORDPRESS

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(feed|wp-atom|wp-feed|wp-rss|wp-rdf|wp-commentsrss)(.+)\ HTTP/ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://feeds.feedburner.com/YourFeedburnerURL? [R=307,L]
RewriteRule ^comments/?.*$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/YourFeedburnerCommentsURL [L,R=302]`

Comment: But we don't have access for .htaccess for free wordpress.com account

Comment: I misread your question.

Comment: but still with css display:none we can't disable the RSS icon in address bar.

Comment: Nothing you can do there

Comment: so it's better to stick with wordpress default.

Comment: You can just put a text widget in the side at with an HTML button from Feedburner.

Comment: Also this won't fix the rss link in the HEAD section used for feed autodiscovery. Could use JavaScript to replace the URL maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about wordpress.com, a webapplication hosting service that is using the wordpress software *but* wordpress.com is not fully in the scope of my answers on this Q&A site, because I don't have access to do administration and support on wordpress.com normally and therefore I'm not able to answer it with the same level of technical detail I can offer for the wordpress blogging software that can be freely downloaded.

Please ask your question to [wordpress.com support](http://en.support.wordpress.com/contact/). In case that does not help you much, there is also a Q&A site dedicated to hosted web-applications (like but not exclusively wordpress.com): [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

I hope at least this information is somehow helpful.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the faq for this site says it's for questions about "the operation of [WordPress] websites which you control". Since you don't control .com, this is out of scope.

Comment: @harke - Currently we have yet to reach a consensus on if WordPress.com is supported here or not. The highest rated answer to the meta question regarding WordPress.com at this time says **yes** WordPress.com is supported here. Please don't tell people it is not until we've actually agreed that it is not.

http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52/

Comment: rightful, that was my opinion, I made some slight modification so that this is more clear.